No wifi/bluetooth connection on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new PC.
Configuration - AMD Ryzen 5 7600, Motherboard - Asus B650-plus wifi tuf gaming.
However, I am not able to connect to Wifi and Bluetooth.
Most of the wifi networks, which I am able to see on my laptop, don't show up and even if they do - all of them no signal bars.
And no bluetooth device connects to my machine as well.
I checked the BIOS settings and I have wifi and bluetooth adapter enabled.
I am not sure what I am missing because the specifications of my motherboard show it should have Wifi and Bluetooth. Do I need to have separate adapters/antenna for bluetooth and wifi?

It's helpful if you're specific with details; you gave a release (22.04) but not product details (eg. 22.04 Server? or 22.04 Desktop?) as they install different kernel stack defaults. Did the wifi work when you tested it in live mode?? and what ISO did you install with? or what I'm really asking here is has the kernel stack changed since install (this may or may not have happened depending on what 22.04 ISO you installed with, but you didn't specify). If it worked reliably in live but not post-install (& after updates), you may have an easy workaround available.

It sounds like a hardware/antenna issue. Have you plugged in an antenna at the back of your motherboard? You could try having a look in the motherboard instructions

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include the script results
